# ros2: is it possible? code, message and action definitions in the same package

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package with actions, messages and code.

The code references the action and messages. However there is a compilation error. It looks like the action include files are not found during the `colcon build` command.

The question is simple: is it possible to use a actions and message definitions from code in the same packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364618/ros2:-is-it-possible?-code,-message-and-action-definitions--in-the-same-package/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2020-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is possible.

Earlier, I have tested it and it works. However, as [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) suggested in [his answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/364618/ros2-is-it-possible-code-message-and-action-definitions-in-the-same-package/?answer=365038#post-id-365038), it is better to keep interface definitions in a separate package.

You need to use `rosidl_target_interfaces`, if you are on Foxy or Galactic. Please check the following answer for detailed instructions:
https://answers.ros.org/question/402196/ros2-configure-a-package-having-idl-files-srv-msg-etc-along-with-cpp/?answer=402218#post-id-402218

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2