# How to correctly define an action and some python code in a ROS2 package?

Tags: ros2, python, action, package.xml, ros-humble

my question is really close to [this one](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/97470/ros2-is-it-possible-code-message-and-action-definitions-in-the-same-package) but with **python** code.

I have a package with an action and some python classes. Those classes use the action and are used in another package.

my package.xml seems correct as my classes are in `$PKG_DIR/install/$MY_PACKAGE/lib/python3.10/site-packages`, but there is no trace of the action in the install directory.

My CMakelists.txt file is likely the same as the one from the [tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Creating-an-Action.html).
But as in my package.xml I use `<build_type>ament_python</build_type>`, does the CMakeLists.txt file really used ?

I'd like to keep the action interface in the same package as it should not be used elsewhere.

Here is my tree:

```
├── action
│   └── <MY_ACTION>.action
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── <MY_PKG>
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── <MY_PYTHON_CLASS>.py
├── include
│   └── <MY_PKG> (empty dir)
├── package.xml
├── resource
│   └── <MY_PKG> (empty file)
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src (empty dir)
```